# Dynamic dispatch in Ruby: strings vs symbols

Tags: ruby, dynamic-dispatch

1. What's the difference between sending a string and sending a symbol to call a method dynamically, e.g., `foo.public_send(:bar)` vs `foo.public_send('bar')`? Is there a concrete difference in how these are handled?
2. If symbols are better, is it worth to do `foo.public_send('bar'.to_sym)` if for some reason you need to construct your method name as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no difference between them, in fact, when passing a *string* it is converted to a *symbol*.
2. No need to convert it since that same conversion (e.g. `'bar'.to_sym`) will be done if a *string* is provided.

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

> Invokes the method identified by *symbol*, passing it any arguments
>   specified. Unlike send, `#public_send` calls public methods only. When
>   the method is identified by a string, the string is converted to a
>   symbol.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Guess I'm blind, I missed that last sentence when I looked for this in the docs :)